# dictionary changed size during iteration but it didnt?

Tags: python

I'm trying to set the keys in a dictionary from a list and the values from another list . but it's giving me this error and I'm not sure what's wrong :

```
code = {"" : "" , "" : "" , "" : ""}
keys = ["a" , "b" , "c"]
values = ["z" , "y" , "x"]
for x, k, v in zip(code, keys, values):
  x = k
  code[x] = v
print(code)
```

Comment: please post the error traceback as well

Comment: You are changing the dictionary `code` during the iteration by typing `code[x] = v` and you are using it on the top of the for loop

Comment: maybe the example has been simplified but doesn't `dict(zip(keys, values))` achieve what you want

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Add the key value pairs?

Comment: keys in dictionary need to be unique so `code` doesn't contain 3 entries as you might think.

Comment: what is the point of using `x = k`  here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
keys = ["a" , "b" , "c"]
values = ["z" , "y" , "x"]
code=dict(zip(keys,values))
print(code)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the right way of doing what you want

```
keys = ["a" , "b" , "c"]
values = ["z" , "y" , "x"]
code = {k:v for k,v in zip(keys,values)}
```